# How do I get all ExtendedManagers from a DynamicValue

Tags: json

I am creating a custom workflow action to be used for building SharePoint 2013 workflows in SharePoint Designer.

I use the *GetPropertiesFor REST API* to get all of a user's information. 
Is there anyway that I can dump all the user names under *d/ExtendedManagers/results* into a collection or dictionary of some sort?

I know how to get an individual manager using the *.../results(x)* notation. And I tried to use the *GetDynamicValueProperties* item in the Visual Studio toolbox, but it seems it only likes to return strings, and doesn't want to return *.../results* as a string.

Is there any easy way to do this, or am I going to have to do a second REST query with a filter that only returns the extended managers?